# How to get the ArgMax of a set in a MiniMax Problem in AMPL

Tags: optimization, scheduling, linear-programming, minimax, ampl

I've a minimax problem to be solved in AMPL. I've a series of processors (`j`) and processes (`i`), with a set of operations to be done by each process in a sequantial way (from processor 1 to processor N) on each processor with a duration for each operation defined by `p[i,j]` 
Every process has an expected end time. 
The task is to schedule the execution of all the processes on processors to **minimize the maximum delay** (defined as the time instant when an execution ends - expected end time). To do that I've tried, as you can see in the following snippet of code, to minimize the max_delay defined in the constraints. The problem is that doing like this it changes *every single delay equal to max_delay*, making a bad scheduling. 
Do you know another way of solving the problem? I also thought about setting `max_delay >= argmax(delay[i])` but honestly I don't know if it's correct and how to implement the argmax function in AMPL

Thanks in advance for the answers, here is the code I've implemented

```
# Parameters
param r >= 0;                                                    # # of PROCESSORS
param T >= 0;                                                    # # of PROCESSES
param t_max >= 0;                                                # TIME max for TIME set

# Sets
set PROCESSES := 1..T;
set PROCESSORS := 1..r;
set TIME := 0..t_max;

# Other params
param D{PROCESSES} >= 0;                                          # exp. end
param p{PROCESSES, PROCESSORS} >= 0;                              # TIME for exec of operation p fro process i on processor j. 

# Variables
var USE{PROCESSES, PROCESSORS, TIME} binary;                
var end_time{PROCESSES} >= 0; 
var DELAY{i in PROCESSES} = end_time[i] - D[i];                   # array of delays
var max_DELAY integer >= 0;

# Constraints

# Constraint to define end_time
subject to end_time_constraint {i in PROCESSES}:
     sum{t in TIME} (t + p[i,r])*USE[i,r,t] <= end_time[i] ;

# constraint to grant a single execution 
subject to single_execution {i in PROCESSES, j in PROCESSORS} : 
    sum{t in TIME} USE[i,j,t]=1;

# Constraint to avoid multiple operation to execute at the same time
subject to operation_constraint {i in PROCESSES, t in TIME}:
    sum{j in PROCESSORS} USE[i,j,t]<=1;

# Constraint to grant the right execution order (operation od process i on processor j befor the one on j+1)
subject to order_constraint {i in PROCESSES, j in PROCESSORS, t in TIME}:
    sum{k in 0..t} USE[i,max(j-1, 1),k] >= USE[i,j,t];

# constraint to get the max delay over delays array

subject to max_DELAY {i in PROCESSES}:
    max_DELAY >= DELAY[i];

# constraint to avoid sovrapposition of processes
subject to non_sovrapp1 {t in TIME, j in PROCESSORS}:
    sum{i in PROCESSES, k in max(t-p[i,j]+1,0)..(t)} USE[i,j,k]<=1;

# constraint to avoid sovrapposition of processors
subject to non_sovrapp2 {i in PROCESSES, t in TIME} :
    sum{ j in PROCESSORS, k in max(t-p[i,j]+1,0)..(t)} USE[i,j,k] <= 1;

minimize min_DELAY : max_DELAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Often we use a combination of `min-max` and `min-sum`. Essentially this becomes a multi-objective problem, for which there are standard solution approaches. One such approach is to first solve the `min-max` problem, and then solve a second `min-sum` subject to the `max` not deteriorating. Alternatively, use a weighted sum formulation. For some details (in a different context), see [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/01/multi-objective-optimization-min-sum-vs.html).